# R: Looping and modifying dates

Tags: r

Suppose I have an incomplete data frame with the dates (already rounded), representing interest rate changes (there is no change if the row is missing):

```
        Date    i
1 2015-03-01 30.0
2 2015-02-01 19.5
3 2014-11-01 14.0
4 2014-08-01 12.5
5 2014-04-01  9.5
6 2013-08-01  6.5
```

I want to add the missing months by copying the value, like this:

```
        Date    i
1 2015-03-01 30.0
2 2015-02-01 19.5
3 2015-01-01 14.0
4 2014-12-01 14.0
5 2014-11-01 14.0
6 2014-10-01 12.5
```

Of course, I can extract the year and month separately as numeric values and construct a new data frame (and the code will look rather complicated). But I believe there must be some elegant way to do it, maybe by looping over the dates somehow and adding a value to the month?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are two steps to take. First, to insert all the missing rows with a merge,

```
DF2   <- merge( 
  data.frame(Date = seq(from = tail(DF$Date,1), to = DF$Date[1], by = "month")), 
  DF, 
  all.x = TRUE)
```

then to fill in the missing values:

```
library(zoo) 
DF2$i <- na.locf(DF2$i)
```

which gives

```
         Date    i
1  2013-08-01  6.5
2  2013-09-01  6.5
3  2013-10-01  6.5
4  2013-11-01  6.5
5  2013-12-01  6.5
6  2014-01-01  6.5
7  2014-02-01  6.5
8  2014-03-01  6.5
9  2014-04-01  9.5
10 2014-05-01  9.5
11 2014-06-01  9.5
12 2014-07-01  9.5
13 2014-08-01 12.5
14 2014-09-01 12.5
15 2014-10-01 12.5
16 2014-11-01 14.0
17 2014-12-01 14.0
18 2015-01-01 14.0
19 2015-02-01 19.5
20 2015-03-01 30.0
```

The `seq` command above will fail if the `Date` column is not of class `Date`. In that case, use `DF$Date <- as.Date(DF$Date)` first. If you want the order backwards (starting with the most recent month, as in the OP), use `DF2[ order(DF2$Date, decreasing = TRUE) ,]`.